# How to find a Chromebook's bluetooth address?

Tags: hardware, google-chrome, bluetooth

I want to quickly find the bluetooth device address (a.k.a. bluetooth address, BD_ADDR, bluetooth mac address) of a Chromebook laptop.

So far, the only way I've found is slow and not always reliable - I've posted this answer below, but feel free to provide a better solution, and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I've seen (and may rely on a failed bluetooth connection attempt or a failed "Smart Lock" setup attempt) is to find a certain warning message in the device logs.

1. Open a tab to: `chrome://system`
2. Click `Expand all` button
3. Ctrl-F to find, and search for `/hci` or `/bluetooth`
4. Note the warning of the form:

   ```
   WARNING:bluetooth_device_chromeos.cc(613)] /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FF_FF_FF_FF_FF_FF: Failed to pair device: ...
   ```

I believe the Chromebook's BD_ADDR is those 6 hex octets, typically written with colons: `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`

*Bonus note*: you can also find the ethernet MAC addresses under `ifconfig` of `chrome://system`